Proximity Messaging not working android 14 after upgrade to android 14
I have used the latest version of the marketing cloud SDK for providing support for target SDK 34 Android as below from official documentation:
marketingcloudsdk = { module = "com.salesforce.marketingcloud:marketingcloudsdk", version.ref = "8.1.5" }
using the above SDK enabling code is not working for  Proximity Messaging though it's working for Geofence Messaging, also I have given all required permission as well(fine and background location).
The previous version of SDK worked fine till 33 but it's not compatible with Android 34 with Google Place service(play-services-location)SDK.
 SFMCSdk.requestSdk { sdk ->
            sdk.mp {
                if (!heathrowPreference.isSalesForceLocationPermissionGranted) {
                    val geofence = it.regionMessageManager.enableGeofenceMessaging()
                    val proximity = it.regionMessageManager.enableProximityMessaging()
                    heathrowPreference.isSalesForceLocationPermissionGranted = true
                    Timber.tag(LOG_TAG).d("GeofenceMessaging $geofence") // its returning true 
                    Timber.tag(LOG_TAG).d("ProximityMessaging $proximity") its returning true 
                }

            }
        }

SDK inner class code
@RequiresPermission(
        allOf = {"android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION", "android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"}
    )
    boolean enableProximityMessaging();

@RequiresPermission(
        allOf = {"android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION", "android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"}
    )
    boolean enableGeofenceMessaging();
```

